# How come a matrix not diagonalizable if the geometric multiplicity is less than the algebraic multiplicity?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I understand that the algebraic multiplicity is the number of times an eigenvalue appears as a root of the characteristic polynomial. I also understand that the geometric multiplicity is the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to some eigenvalue. I do not understand why having an eigenvalue appear *m+1* times in the characteristic polynomial while having a dimension of *m* means that it is not diagonalizable. Is these something I am missing in my understanding of one of these concepts? It is not clear to me how they are connected.

Comment: Contrapositive. Suppose $A$ _is_ diagonalisable, so that say $X^{-1}AX = \Lambda$ (diagonal matrix of eigenvalues). Then columnwise, $AX = X\Lambda$ is of the form $Ax = \lambda x$, and you get as many independent eigenvectors for each $\lambda$ as the multiplicity of $\lambda$ (the number of times it appears along the diagonal of $\Lambda$) – the vectors being independent because they're columns of the invertible matrix $X$.

Comment: See http://www.math.tamu.edu/~stecher/323/diagonalizationTheorems.pdf

Comment: Following what M. Vinay said, now that means that there are $n$ independent eigenvectors if the ambient space has dimension $n$. But the sum of the algebraic multiplicities is $n$, so this cannot happen unless all the geometric multiplicities equal the corresponding algebraic multiplicities.

Comment: diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial is squarefree ( product of distinct linear terms)

Comment: Simply because the sum of the dimension of the eigen spaces don't add up to the dimension of the vector space.  Hence there's no basis consisting of eigenvectors ...